# YII2 - How to get a field value from form for search

Tags: php, mysql, forms, yii2

I am a new in Yii2 and in MVC, so think that answer to question is simple, but did not found the answer from documentation and tutorials. So, I need to select a record with corresponding id from the database table. So, here the steps that I am following:

1) I created a model (CustomerReport) with CRUD generator for corresponding table and added it on the view where :

```
use app\models\CustomerReport;
```

2) On the view page I had tested it with

```
$customer_data = CustomerReport::findone(['id' => 2]);
```

This works OK for me

3) I added a Search form on the view:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'customer-report']); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'id') ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'contact-button']) ?>
                </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

But I could not find the way to perform a search by id via form. As I understand, I need to provide search field value into

```
$customer_data = CustomerReport::findone(['id' => VALUE FROM ACTIVE FORM]);
```

Comment: When you submit the form, it should hit a route.  The route should hit the controller, the controller should hit the model passing input data to it.  Then the model should return the results to the controller, the controller should then decide what to do with it. IE make a new view or pass a message to the user.

Comment: Please include the model, view, controller, and the routes for this

Comment: _When you submit the form, it should hit a route._ - could you tell more where this route is defined?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

Comment: Am I understanding right that I should always insert record id in the route? E.g.          /index.php?r=post/view&id=100
/index.php/post/100
/posts/100 Is it possible to create an action like POST request in PHP procedural style?

Comment: That is right.  This is called RESTful Routing.  It is more advanced than because it uses URIs and not URLs.

Comment: How about getting field value? Are you understood how realize it? I want know.

Comment: Still can't do this. Or may be I do not understand. Why I could not hook the value from the search form after pressing "Search button"?

Answer (score 0):

Controller knows what is in the object returned by the view Search form

```
$customer_data = CustomerReport::findone(['id' => $model->id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your file where these form get POSTed (probable XyzController.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['CustomerReport']['id'])  // after form get POSTed
    $customer_data = CustomerReport::findone(['id' => $_POST['CustomerReport']['id']]);
```